# Error installing fakeXrandr library on Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu OS)

Tags: linux, display, ubuntu

I have successfully installed a ubuntu image on my Raspberry Pi 4. I am trying to do some screen customization, and so as a result I'm looking to install this project, fakeXrandr:

https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr

Following their install steps, after installing some dependencies, I get the following error which seems related to my architecture (i.e. the RPi):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/fakexrandr-master$ sudo make
./configure
XRandR version is 1.5.2
The path to the real XRandR library is /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXrandr.so.2

ERROR: Failed to find a suitable directory for the fakeXrandr library

You must place the library into the library search path, in a directory preceeding
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf. In your system, this leaves the following candidates:

None of these contains `local', therefore I won't autoconfigure the installation to one
of these directories. Either add a high-priority directory in /usr/local using the ldconfig
mechanism (See /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ on most systems) or manually create config.h.

make: *** [Makefile:7: config.h] Error 1
```

Any ideas how I can overcome this? I have little experience on linux systems and don't know how to use `ldconfig` or any other of the resources mentioned in the error. Answers much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a ubuntu user so have no image to check, but some distros don't configure `/usr/local` into paths searched by the system runtime (dynamic) linker.  This is pretty easy to fix, but first check if it is the case:

```
grep local /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
```

If this doesn't return anything:

```
echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
ldconfig
```

Both of those require root privileges; **the first won't work with `sudo`** because of the redirection, but the point is you want a one line file with `/usr/local/lib` in it.

See also `man ld.so`.

Comment: Great thanks so much for your answer. I'll try now and get back to you shortly.

Comment: `sudo echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf/local.conf
bash: /etc/ld.so.conf/local.conf: Not a directory` Do I need to make that a directory? Or is it a file? Not sure what to do.

Comment: Whoops! I left off the `.d`.  Corrected, try all that again.  `man ldconfig` should explain what all this is about.  **The `sudo echo` won't work** as originally mentioned, but you should be able to use `sudo sh -c echo ...`.

Comment: OK, I used `sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` to add the one line `/usr/local/lib`. Then I ran `sudo ldconfig`. Then I ran `sudo make` but wound up with the same error still as in the OP. (and I verified that my vim editing saved the line into the file.)